# Can different calendar apps coexist without interfering with each other?

Tags: calendar, 6.0-marshmallow, google-calendar, nexus-6p

I have multiple personal Google calendars (all under the same email address), and I have an Exchange calendar for work.

I'd like to use the Google Calendar app for my personal calendars and alerts, and then use the Business Calendar app for my work calendar.  I have widgets set up for each app, running okay.

Here's the rub: If I open Google Calendar, and disable display of my work calendar in there, it also disables it in the Business Calendar app. And vice versa.

So my question is: can you have multiple calendar apps on the same device without them interfering with each other?

Nexus 6p, running Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple calendar apps but am not sure why. But it is possible to have multiple calendar within Google calendar. In case that works for you http://www.androidtipsandhacks.com/android/sync-multiple-calendars/

Comment: thanks, but I'm already running four personal calendars within Google Calendar. I'm just looking for a way to keep a second calendar app from interfering with Google Calendar.

Comment: I think it is not possible since calendar storage is only one....

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the solution to your problem, but this is what I do to choose which calendar(s) to display on the app.

I see that you use Business Calendar app, which I am also using.  Under "Calendars & Task lists" setting you are able to "favorite" your calendar(s) to be displayed at the bottom by tapping on the star(s) on the right.  Once done, I just have to tap on the bottom buttons (those favorite) to switch between my personal and business calendars.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do it- only keep the account you want to use with a calendar app setup in Accounts (like your personal calendar). Then open a browser to view your other calendar there.  It's not a great solution but simple, especially if you make a shortcut to that webpage on your phone's home screen. (Note: if both are gmail accounts, don't use Chrome if you have signed in as both accounts there. Use another browser or your phone's default internet app.)